# Change of basis into specific values?

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

Which $a$ value turns the vector $\mathbf{u}=(9, -1, 6)$ into $\mathbf{u'}=(1, 2, 3)$. (From basis $\mathbf{e_1}$, $\mathbf{e_2}$, $\mathbf{e_3}$ to basis $\mathbf{e'_1}$, $\mathbf{e'_2}$, $\mathbf{e'_3}$)

Where:

\begin{equation}
\begin{cases}
\mathbf{e'_1}=\mathbf{e_1}+\mathbf{e_2}+\mathbf{e_3} \\ \mathbf{e'_2}=\mathbf{e_1}+2\mathbf{e_2}+\mathbf{e_3} \\ \mathbf{e'_3}=2\mathbf{e_1}+a\mathbf{e_2}+\mathbf{e_3}
\end{cases}
\end{equation}

I tried solving for $\mathbf{e_1}$, $\mathbf{e_2}$, $\mathbf{e_3}$ and inserting **u**'s  values into the resulting system of equations. That didn't work and now I have no idea what to do.

The answer should be $a = -2$.

Comment: You are probably over-thinking this.  Most likely $\mathbf{e_1},\mathbf{e_2},\mathbf{e_3}$ are the standard basis vectors, so you don't solve for them.

Comment: @hardmath That's actually irrelevant.

Comment: @AlexR: It seems relevant to say you don't solve for $\mathbf{e_1},\mathbf{e_2},\mathbf{e_3}$.  Whatever the choice of ordered basis for $\mathbf{u}=(9,-1,6)$, it may as well be the "standard basis" as far as the coordinate computation is concerned.

Comment: @hardmath That, I agree with. But the "Most likely ..." part (i.e. the actual meaning of the first comment), I do not agree with.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We know that respect to the basis $\beta' = \{ e_1',e_2',e_3'\}$ that $u_{\beta'} = (1,2,3)$, so
\begin{align*}
u &= e_1' + 2e_2'+3e_3' \\
&= (e_1 + e_2 + e_3) + 2(e_1+2e_2+e_3) + 3(2e_1 + ae_2 + e_3) \\
&= 9e_1 + (5+3a)e_2 + 6e_3.
\end{align*}
However, we know that with respect to the basis $\beta = \{ e_1,e_2,e_3\}$, $u_{\beta} = (9,-1,6)$. Thus $u = 9e_1 - e_2 + 6 e_3$. Combining this with the above computation, we see that it must be the case that $5+3a = -1$. This implies that $a=-2$

Sidenote: I am highlighting here that $u$ and $u'$ are the same object. Or at least they should be thought as the same. What is changing is its position with respect to our different bases.

Answer (score 1):

The equations can be read off as
$$\pmatrix{1&1&2\\1&2&a\\1&1&1} \pmatrix{1\\2\\3} = \pmatrix{9\\-1\\6}$$
($e_1' = e_1 + e_2 + e_3$ dictates the first column, $\Big(\begin{smallmatrix}1\\1\\1\end{smallmatrix}\Big)$, for example)
The only relevant equation is the middle one.

Answer (score 1):

Use change of basis matrix (from basis $\mathcal B$ to basis $\mathcal B'$):

$$P=\begin{bmatrix}1&1&2\\
1&2&a\\1&1&1\end{bmatrix}$$

You should have $\begin{bmatrix}9\\-1\\6\end{bmatrix}=P\begin{bmatrix}1\\2\\3\end{bmatrix}$.